# C array reverse in some range

Tags: c

I made a c code.

```
array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

and the range can be `(0, 3)`, `(2, 6)` etc.

But my code has problem it works some range but some range it didn't work well. I don't know the reason.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(int arr[], int s, int t)
{
    int i,j, temp;

    for (i=s, j=0; i<(t-s)/2 + 1; i++, j++)
    {                       
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[t-j];
            arr[t-j] = temp; 
    }       

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            printf("%d   ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
 }
 int main()
 {
    int i, s, t;

    printf("start =   ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("end = ");
    scanf("%d", &t);

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    reverse(arr, s, t);

    return 0;
 }
```

This is correct result.

[image]

This is wrong result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to show some examples of ranges that don't work (and show the output you get for them)

Comment: Write a reverse that works for an entire array. Then C allows you to create a sub-range by passing the address of the first element and the number of sub-elements you want. Not something I normally recommend, but I'll make an exception here.

Comment: Your end condition in the loop is wrong. If you have s = 7 and t = 8. It evaluates to i < (8 - 7) / 2 + 1; which would be 1. And your i starts at 7.

Comment: Why did you update the code with the fixes offered bellow? Now it makes those answers incorrect. It's completely disrespectful to the people who actually took the time to review your code **in your stead**.

Comment: I am really sorry about that. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(int arr[], int s, int t)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = s, j = 0; i <= (t-s)/2 + s; i++, j++) {                       
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[t-j];
            arr[t-j] = temp; 
    }       

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            printf("%d   ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
 int main()
 {
    int i, s, t;
    printf("start =   ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("end = ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    reverse(arr, s, t);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: if we consider s = 4 and t = 7, if you use (i< (t-s)/2 + s) the counter stops before the 5th index so one variable will be changed( in our case 5 and 8 were reversed) and we exited the loop.But when choose (i<= (t-s)/2 + s) the counter finished til the 5th index so it take the variable arr[5] in consideration.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you got the solution ;)

Comment: Ok, I will find it!

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code:

```
for (i=s, j=0; i<(t-s)/2 + s; i++, j++)
```

Instead of your:

```
for (i=s, j=0; i<(t-s)/2 + 1; i++, j++)
```